# Social dystopia requiring conformant behavior

Tags: story-identification, movie, novel, dystopia, society

I am trying to remember the name of a film I saw where people have to
abandon their own personality and free will to adapt to the standard
of a community, similar in theme to "The Stepford wives". The unadapted character is a boy (I forgot the name of the film) who ends up killed with parental approval. Another detail of the film that somehow stuck with me is that in the end they plant a tree on the grave, never saying it is a grave, among other similar trees.

I think I saw it on DVD. I would also like to know whether it exists as a novel.

Comment: We The Living - Ayn Rand; I don't know that this is an enumerable list...

Comment: Also Ayn Rand: [Anthem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthem_%28novella%29)

Comment: I really don't think it's either Ayn Rand or Harrison Bergeron, nor The Handmaid's Tale.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're describing the 2002 **Twilight Zone** episode [Evergreen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evergreen_(The_Twilight_Zone)).  In an exclusive gated community, rebellious teens are sent to the "Arcadia Military Academy", but it turns out Arcadia is really a fertilizer company.  The parents plant a tree as a memorial and feed it with the remains of their child.

Comment: It sounds extremely close to what I saw (I also checked IMDB). It could be the answer. But I recall it a full movie on DVD, not as a 44mn episode. And I do not recall watching or having access to the 2002 Twilight Zone. I am giving myself some time for more searching ... but it is at least so close that I am upvoting the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Check out "Harrison Bergeron" by Kurt Vonnegut Jr. There was a 90s movie adaption with Sean Astin. Another good one to check out would be the "Handmaids Tale".

-Eric-

Comment: Definitely not *The Handmaid's Tale* as it has an adult female protagonist and a different theme altogether.

Comment: @lea No, it is not *The Handmaid's Tale*, whih I know. I do not believe it is *Harrison Bergeron* which I checked on IMDB.

Comment: Harrison Bergeron (in the film adaptation) is killed by the state, and does not have a tree-marked grave.